# My code does not compile, CCTL0 undefined

Tags: embedded, msp430, texas-instruments

Sorry about a newbie question. Trying to port this code to msp430f5529. It does not compile, says "Identifier CCTL0 undefined". Am I using a wrong clock? A wrong .h? Both?

```
//***************************************************************************************
// MSP430 Timer Blink LED Demo - Timer A Software Toggle P1.0 & P1.6
//
// Description; Toggle P1.0 and P1.6 by xor'ing them inside of a software loop.
// Since the clock is running at 1Mhz, an overflow counter will count to 8 and then toggle
// the LED. This way the LED toggles every 0.5s.
// ACLK = n/a, MCLK = SMCLK = default DCO
//4
// MSP430G2xx
// -----------------
// /|\| XIN|-
// | | |
// --|RST XOUT|-
// | P1.6|-->LED
// | P1.0|-->LED
//
// Aldo Briano
// Texas Instruments, Inc
// June 2010
// Built with Code Composer Studio v4
//***************************************************************************************
//#include <msp430g2231.h>
//#include <msp430.h>
#include <msp430f5529.h>

#define LED_0 BIT0
#define LED_1 BIT6
#define LED_OUT P1OUT
#define LED_DIR P1DIR

unsigned int timerCount = 0;

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void main(void)
{
    WDTCTL = WDTPW + WDTHOLD; // Stop watchdog timer
    LED_DIR |= (LED_0 + LED_1); // Set P1.0 and P1.6 to output direction
    LED_OUT &= ~(LED_0 + LED_1); // Set the LEDs off

    CCTL0 = CCIE;
    TACTL = TASSEL_2 + MC_2; // Set the timer A to SMCLCK, Continuous
// Clear the timer and enable timer interrupt

    __enable_interrupt();

    __bis_SR_register(LPM0 + GIE); // LPM0 with interrupts enabled

}

// Timer A0 interrupt service routine
#pragma vector=TIMERA0_VECTOR
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
__interrupt void Timer_A(void)
{
    timerCount = (timerCount + 1) % 8;

    if (timerCount == 0)
        P1OUT ^= (LED_0 + LED_1);
}
```

Comment: What do you think CCTL0 is or should be? Where did you get that from? I assume you think it's a timer register or at least it was a timer register in the original code. I would imagine that the timer registers are named [slightly] differently with this processor or if you're porting it from code compiled with a different compiler, the header files are different in the original compiler. Without know what register in the peripheral you think you are programming it's hard to say.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't worked with the F5529, but I have worked with other F5x family, namely F5437 & F5438 in A and non-A versions.

You have to port the example to your device, so the CCTL0 & TACTL registers have to be replaced with YOUR microcontroller registers. Take a look at you [device's datasheet](http://www.ti.com/general/docs/lit/getliterature.tsp?genericPartNumber=msp430f5529&fileType=pdf).
It will surely be something in the form of:
TAxCCTL0
and
TAxCTL
Where x is the timer you are using.

From what I can see in the code you will be using TimerA0, so that will make them TA0CCTL0 and TA0CTL.

Hope this helps.